# Get value from R fullfilled promise

Tags: r, asynchronous, promise, future

I read many articles about `R` `promises` (including [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/promises/vignettes/intro.html)) and still don't get it.

See code:

```
library(future)
library(promises)
plan(multiprocess)

read.csv.async <- function(file, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) {
  future({
    read.csv(file, header = header, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors)
  })
}

df_promise <- read.csv.async("https://rstudio.github.io/promises/data.csv")

df_promise %...>% filter(state == "NY")

df_filtered_promise <- df_promise %...>% filter(state == "NY")

df_filtered_promise

class(df_filtered_promise)
```

Output:

```
> read.csv.async <- function(file, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) {
+   future({
+     read.csv(file, header = header, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors)
+   })
+ }
> 
> df_promise <- read.csv.async("https://rstudio.github.io/promises/data.csv")
> 
> df_promise %...>% filter(state == "NY")
> 
> df_filtered_promise <- df_promise %...>% filter(state == "NY")
> 
> df_filtered_promise
<Promise [pending]>
> df_filtered_promise
<Promise [fulfilled: data.frame]>
> class(df_filtered_promise)
[1] "promise"
```

Why **fullfilled** `promise` doesn't return its value? How can I extract data frame in my case?

Comment: @r2evans I don't ask how `future` works, but `promises`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought they were close enough, but you're right, I rushed.

Comment: the code wont work for me:> read.csv.async <- function(file, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) {
+   future({
+     read.csv(file, header = header, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors)
+   })
+ }
> df_promise <- read.csv.async("https://rstudio.github.io/promises/data.csv")
> df_promise %...>% filter(state == "NY")
Error in df_promise %...>% filter(state == "NY") : 
  could not find function "%...>%"

Comment: @DanielFischer just add `library(promises)`

Comment: I find their [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/combining.html) a little incomplete: I can, for instance, do `df_promise %...>% print()` and it will print it out, but I don't want it *printed*, I want it *realized/gathered*. I wonder if the intent for `promises` is really not at all user-interactive so much as `shiny` (for which it works well).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a way to do this, but before I tell you, I would advise you not to use promises for interactive or scripting use, probably. Synchronous programming is more convenient than asynchronous, and you should only do the latter if it's very important not to tie up the main R thread (as is the case with Shiny if you want to keep apps responsive while long operations run).

If you choose to use future, try to get away with not chaining any `%...>%` operations after it, and then you can simply use `future::value` as Daniel Fischer said.

If you do decide to fully use promises, and it's important to you to extract the value out into a regular variable, then you can accomplish this via side effects, like this super-assign:

```
df_filtered <- NULL
df_filtered_promise %...>% { df_filtered <<- . }
```

This will cause the `df_filtered` variable to be set to the result of `df_filtered_promise` at some point in the future. (It will never be assigned in the case of error, though.)

This generally ought not be done in Shiny, as you usually want to keep things wrapped in promises all the way to the end of the computation so Shiny can keep track of what outputs/observers are waiting on what operations.

Comment: > "I would advise you not to use promises for interactive or scripting use, probably."  The complexity of `promises` is indeed daunting and I haven't chosen to use it in a script for 'fun.'  The `RLesur/crrri` package relies on promises and if you want to extract the html results in a script, you need to do **something** like this (I landed here because I was desperate to return/collect my crri/promises html results without using a super/global assign).  Looks like that's the best we can do for now.

Answer (score 5):

df <- environment (promise_object[["then"]])[["private"]][["value"]]  is what you are looking for.

Promise object stores data and properties in a nested list format and that list is part of the environment object.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue? Check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.

Answer (score 0):

```r
promise %>% 
  {.$then} %>% 
  environment %>% 
  {.$private$value}
```

You can try this.

If `promise` is not fullfilled, this will return `NULL`.

---

e.g.

```r
seq(3) %>% promises::promise_map(\ (a) a+1) -> promise

(\ (promise) promise %>% 
    {.$then} %>% environment %>% 
    {while (.$private$state != "fulfilled") {
        
        message (.$private$state," ..."); Sys.sleep(1)
        }; .$private$value} %>% 
    
{.}) (promise)
```

If you submit these code to console **once**, it will `prnding ...` forever; but if you submit these code **one by one**, it will return the result. So if you want to get the result out of the `promise` box in a script, you will fail.

So how can we use the value inside that `promise` box ? The answer (may be only one) is use `then` or `%...>%` pipe. And if you have many value in several `promise` box, you can do something like this:

```r
seq(3) %>% promises::promise_map(\ (a) a+1) -> promise0
seq(1) %>% promises::promise_map(\ (a) a+1) -> promise1

promise0 %>% 
    promises::then (\ (a) promise1 %>% 
        promises::then (\ (b) (a %>% unlist) - (b %>% unlist))) %>% 
    promises::then (\ (x) x %T>% print %>% class %>% print)
```

Or clearly, use `promise_all`:

```r
seq(3) %>% promises::promise_map (\ (a) a+1) -> promise0
seq(1) %>% promises::promise_map (\ (a) a+1) -> promise1

promise_ab = promises::promise_all (a = promise0, b = promise1)

promise_ab %>% 
    promises::then (\ (x) (x$a %>% unlist) - (x$b %>% unlist)) %>% 
    promises::then (\ (x) x %T>% print %>% class %>% print)
```

(For me, I like the future more ... )

Answer (score -2):

you have to use value function:

```
value(df_filtered_promise)
```

Comment: No: `> future::value(df_filtered_promise) Error in UseMethod("value") : no applicable method for 'value' applied to an object of class "promise"`